Are "lay the newspaper on the floor" and "spread the newspaper on the floor" interchangeable?
Normally "lay" means "to put somebody/something in a particular position" (meaning 1) but it also means "to spread something on something" (meaning 2).
So, "lay the newspaper on the floor" could mean:
1- you just put it down on the floor and the newspaper could be somewhat crumpled or folded (meaning 1).
2- you unfolded the newspaper and put it flat on the floor (meaning 2).
Are "lay the newspaper on the floor" and "spread the newspaper on the floor" interchangeable because "lay" can cause confusion?

It's just a matter of looking at the dictionary definitions for lay and spread, and combining that with your real-world knowledge of the typical newspaper "form factor" (a number of relatively large interleaved  folded sheets / pages). In most cases the meanings of lay and spread would be considered equivalent in the imperative "Please lay / spread the newspaper on the floor" (unfold all the single sheets and place them on the floor with small overlaps so the entire relevant area is covered). But in principle, lay might not include unfold.

This is something that would depend a lot on the context in the rest of the paragraph. Looking at the definitions of lay from Merriam-Webster and Cambridge dictionaries you could make an argument for spread being interchangeable. The Cambridge defintion of the verb:

to put something in especially a flat or horizontal position, usually carefully or for a particular purpose

would indicate that the use of lay in your statement could be communicating how forcefully the person is placing the newspaper. However, if we consider the much more varied definitions Merriam-Webster provide:

2.a: to put or set down, lay your books on the table

it does not tell us how forcefully the paper is put down, just that an object is put/set down on a surface.
Considering the use of spread, this has a much more specific meaning. If one were to spread out a newspaper they would not simply be placing it on a surface, they would also be fully opening it. Consider the Merriam-Webster definition of spread:

1.a: to open or expand over a larger area, spread out the map

and also Cambridge:

to open something that has been folded or make something flat, so it covers a larger area

The two definitions both describe a similar event, in our case the newspaper being placed on the surface and opened. This is not the same as lay which usually describes how forceful someone is in placing an object down but doesn't explicitly mean opening of that placed object.
TL;DR: If you were looking to replace a sentence in a paragraph without significantly changing the meaning I would argue that replacing "spread the newspaper on the floor" could be replaced by "lay the newspaper on the floor" but not the other way around. This is because spread offers much more detail about the action taking place whereas it is up to the reader about how to interpret lay. If lay were used in the original paragraph it could mean the paper was gently placed down on the floor in an folded, or still partially folded, state.

Pretty much interchangable because the context would make more difference that the meaning of the words.
"lay" suggests flat on the ground
"spread" suggests covering a wider area
since to "spread" newspapers you would need to "lay" them, and if you "lay" them, you probably do so in order to "spread" them,  the two are equivalent, in context.

And if you were talking about a folded newspaper you would probably use put rather than lay.
